# Command-Line requires file as a parameter, how to pass a variable from a Python program and write into?

Tags: python, bash, shell, cmd

Say, I have command line utility, where **output file** is mandatory argument:

```
process_data <output file>
```

What I want is to be able to run this CMD command from Python code,
but instead of storing result to file store it into Python variable (kinda redirect it):

```
variable = None  # currently empty 

os.system(f"process_data {variable}")
```

By the end of the utility runtime I wish to get content into that variable, that was supposed to be written to the "output file":

```
print("output: ", variable)
output: "Data is processed successfully, here is the content of processing: ..."
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear about what you exactly want? As your post is currently written, it is very hard to make out what your exact question is.

Comment: @The_spider is it cleaner now? Long story short, I wish to write content of CMD command output directly into Python variable, however this "command" itself MUSt HAVE "output file" as a parameter, how to be ?:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is here:

```
variable = None

response = subprocess.run(["process_data", "/dev/stdout"], capture_output=True)


variable = response.stdout
```

In case of text output I'd recommend to add "text=True" flag:

```
response = subprocess.run(["process_data", "/dev/stdout"], capture_output=True, text=True)
```

It is good to have a "timeout=..." flag, in case your cmd is hung:

```
response = subprocess.run(["process_data", "/dev/stdout"], capture_output=True, text=True, timeout=10)
```

Don't forget to always check on:

```
if response.returncode != 0:
          # do something :)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This one works for me, I guess the trick here is to add "/dev/stdout" and then just capture it haha, nice :)

Comment: @Azii I just had same issue before :DDD

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way to call an external program is to use python `subprocess` module. And you have two main way of using it.

### If you just want to call the program and wait for the output without catching it:

```py
import subprocess

variable = None

subprocess.call(["process_data", variable])
```

The output will be printed in stdout but you will not get it in a python variable.
However you can also specify not to show the output to the user using additional arguments.

### If you want to store the output in a variable:

```py
import subprocess

variable = None

out = subprocess.check_output(["process_data", variable])
```

EDIT: in my example, variable is an argument to `process_data`, not the variable to store the output in

Comment: Thanks for your time, first of all! :D But this, unfortunately, doesn't solve my issue.. :(

Btw, to make it cleaner. I wish to tell to the CMD command "process_data <out file>", where <out file>" is MANDATORY parameter, that DON'T write to file, instead write to Python variable. The problem to overcome is to tell the command (CMD) that <out file> == Python variable, somehow..